# Skipping first keyframes animation

Tags: css, animation

I am working on a project which uses an api to receive new data. I don't have control of `HTML` all i can do is change `CSS`. I am using `@keyframes animation` animate new set of data that is received.

Here is the simple css i am using

```
@keyframes newActivity{      
    to{
        position: absolute;
        top: 18%;
        left: 10%;
        z-index: 1;
        width:500px;
        height:80%;    
   }

}
.apiData{
    animation-name:newActivity;
    animation-duration:5s;
}
```

I receive new data as div element with class .apiData. My problem is that when the page loads it fetch previous data with same div class and it also animates it.

I want to animate only the new data and prevent old data from animating when page reloads. Looking for a way to skip the first animation when the page loads

Comment: are you trying to only target one div? is that your question?

Comment: Yes a single div that i am receiving with same class and cant change HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the last div to be animated you can do it like this:

```
.apiData:last-child {
 animation-name:newActivity;
 animation-duration:5s;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but doing this will also animate the last div in the previous data i received with api on page reload

Comment: You are going to have to add more to your question then, how are you loading the divs and how many of the divs have the same class?

Comment: I have a js file of api which loads div and place them in my document. All div have same class no way to distinguish between them.  No. Of divs i already have is between 0 - 15

Comment: On each api call i receive 1 div and its placed in the document